# Preg-replace - Replace title if contain a word if not do nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace this titles:

```
Page 1 - example.com
Page 2 - example.com
Search engine optimization - example.com
```

I **don't** want to replace this titles:

```
Page 1
Page 2
Search engine optimization
```

So only if the contain example.com then I want to replace it. I've tried something like this:

```
$document = preg_replace('#(<title[^>]*>)(.*)[(example.com)][^<]+</title>#i', '$1Welcome to my site</title>', $document);
```

But that is not working. Somebody has an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document = preg_replace("/(<title>)(.*?) - example.com(<\/title>)/", "$1$2$3", $document)
```